# Disable exception chaining in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

There is a new feature that was introduced in python3 - exception chaining. For some reasons I need to disable it for certain exceptions in my code.

Here is sample code:

```
try:
    print(10/0)
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    sys.exc_info()
    raise AssertionError(str(e))
```

what I see:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "draft.py", line 19, in main
    print(10/0)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "draft.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "draft.py", line 22, in main
    raise AssertionError(str(e))
AssertionError: division by zero
```

what I want to see:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "draft.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "draft.py", line 22, in main
    raise AssertionError(str(e))
AssertionError: division by zero
```

I tried to use `sys.exc_clear()`, but this method is removed from python 3 too.
I can use workaround that works

```
exc = None
try:
    print(10/0)
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    exc = e
if exc:
    raise AssertionError(str(exc))
```

but I believe that there is better solution.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

## Simple Answer

```
try:
    print(10/0)
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    raise AssertionError(str(e)) from None
```

However, you probably actually want:

```
try:
    print(10/0)
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    raise AssertionError(str(e)) from e
```

## Explanation

#### `__cause__`

Implicit exception chaining happens through `__context__` when there isn't an explicit cause exception set.

Explicit exception chaining works through `__cause__` so if you set `__cause__` to the exception itself, it should stop the chaining. If `__cause__` is set, Python will suppress the implicit message.

```
try:
    print(10/0)
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    exc = AssertionError(str(e))
    exc.__cause__ = exc
    raise exc
```

#### raise from

We can use "raise from" to do the same thing:

```
try:
    print(10/0)
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    exc = AssertionError(str(e))
    raise exc from exc
```

#### None `__cause__`

Setting `__cause__` to `None` actually does the same thing:

```
try:
    print(10/0)
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    exc = AssertionError(str(e))
    exc.__cause__ = None
    raise exc
```

#### raise from None

So that brings us to **the most elegant way** to do this which is to **raise from `None`**:

```
try:
    print(10/0)
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    raise AssertionError(str(e)) from None
```

But I would argue that you usually want to explicitly raise your exception from the cause exception so the traceback is preserved:

```
try:
    print(10/0)
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    raise AssertionError(str(e)) from e
```

This will give us a slightly different message that states that the first exception was the direct cause of the second:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
AssertionError: division by zero
```